# ¿Qué ventajas ofrece SASS comparado con CSS?

Tags: java, css, primefaces, sass

En esta ocasión quiero consultarles cual es la ventaja de trabajar el diseño con SASS.

Por mas que me he documentado las ventajas solo llegan a manejar variables que puedes reutilizar en la creación del CSS, sera que me estoy perdiendo de algo mas, ya que veo que primefaces lo usa mucho, y eso me genera la intriga que me estoy perdiendo de algo mas.

Desde el punto de vista de alguien que no conozca sass, ¿Que características principales puede aportarnos? ¿Algún ejemplo en su forma de uso?

Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask], esperemos al resto de la comunidad, pero pareciera **no estar relacionada con dudas sobre temas de programación**

Comment: Esto es algo que comentaba el usuario @Sergio: 1º, que permite crear variables y funciones (mixins). Esto es una grandísima diferencia. Por ejemplo, creas una "función" para que en base a unos parámetros, muestres un tipo de tamañó u otro. Puedes generar compatibilidades con mas dispositivos o realizar calculos de ajuste de tamaños para un diseño mas responsive. Y aplicar este mismo comportamiento en toda tu web.

Comment: Esto es algo que comentaba el usuario @Sergio: Partiendo que CSS es mas ligero que el JS, puedes utilizar estilos (CSS/SASS) para realizar buen diseño, efectos y aligerar la plataforma en lugar de abusar del JS como en ocasiones se hace..

Comment: Esto es algo que comentaba el usuario @Sergio:
2º, la capacidad que tiene de modificar todos tus estilos y mantener una homogeneidad en todo tu proyecto. Evitar que unos textos queden mas grandes que otros o tener que acordarte de que diseño le diste a cada "sección" de tu plataforma.

Comment: muchas gracias por tus comentarios @Jorgesys tus comentarios son bien recibidos y sin duda aportan a mi investigación sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, bienvenido a StackOverflow!

Las ventajas son muchas

**1º**, Permite **crear variables y funciones** (mixins). Esto es una grandísima diferencia. 
Por ejemplo, creas una "función" para que en base a unos parámetros, muestres un tipo de tamañó u otro. Puedes generar compatibilidades con mas dispositivos o realizar calculos de ajuste de tamaños para un diseño mas responsive. Y aplicar este mismo comportamiento en toda tu web.

**2º**, Capacidad que tiene de modificar todos tus estilos y mantener una **homogeneidad en todo tu proyecto**. Evitar que unos textos queden distintos unos de otros, utilizar misma tonalidad de colores, y poder modificar todo esto de 1 golpe cambiando una variable.

Piensa que en un proyecto pequeño, puede no ser tan obvio, pero he tenido la suerte de trabajar en proyectos de Magento, con mas de 15 o 20 archivos de estilos, y cada uno con mas de 500 lineas.., puede ser duro modificar estilos si no es con SASS. A demás, permites un código mas escalable, limpio, en resumen, tu plataforma lucirá mucho mejor si presenta homogeneidad en sus estilos.

**3º** Te permite mantener tu **código de estilos mucho mas organizados**, también aumenta la flexibilidad y escalabilidad, puesto que encapsulas el código de una sección, como si de un módulo se tratara y luego al compilar se evitan duplicidades.

Obviamente como en toda la tecnología, lo suyo es adaptarte a tus necesidades, pero por experiencia personal, dejaría el CSS como para proyectos mas pequeños o donde no queda otro remedio. Siempre que puedas aprovecha SASS.

```
https://sass-lang.com/guide
```

Te invito a leer mas documentación y probar hacer tus propias estructuras de estilos

Un ejemplo para plasmar las ideas citadas:

Inicialmente tienes un archivo global.scss

En este defines que otros archivos SCSS se van a compilar y en que orden

```
@import 'layout/normalize'
@import 'layout/base';
```

EN el archivo base.scss puedes tener algo así

```
// Colores genericos
$c-red: #CF5050;
$c-yellow: #FFDA14;
$c-green: #13B400;
// Colores para textos
$c-text: #636363;
$c-text-gray: #A0A0A0;
$c-text-white: #E6E6E6;
// Encabezados
$c-h1: $c-red;
$c-h2: $c-yellow;
$c-h4: $c-text;
// Tamaño de tipografias
$f-size-sm: 13px;
$f-size-md: 14px;
```

Así trabajas rápido con variables que mas o menos te acuerdas, mas facil que recordar ¿Cuantos píxeles puse en tal sitio? Si sabes que los parrafos son md por ejemplo. Por asociación se trabaja mas facil.

Un ejemplo de mixin para mejorar la compatibilidad entre navegadores, cada vez que generas un keyframe, pues al hacerlo con esto, generará el código compatible al compilar el css. Tu solo escribes 1 linea. Y al comienzo de tu aplicación, dices si esas variables están activas o no, si quieres generar compatibilidad para todos o para solo algunos.

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
  @if $webkit == true {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @if $moz == true {
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @if $ms == true {
    @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @if $o == true {
    @-o-keyframes #{$name} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Saludos!